# How to append or change data within a file

Tags: file, python-3.x, store

Hiya i have made a program that stores the player name and strength..Here is the code:

```
data = {
    "PLAYER":name2,
    "STRENGTH":str(round(strength, 2)),

}


with open("data2.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
   file.write(repr(data))
file.close()
```

So this stores the data so what to i do if i wanna append/change the value after a certain action usch as a 'BATTLE'

Is it possible the get the variable of 'STRENGTH' and then change the number?

At the moment to read data from the external file 'DATA1.txt'i am using this code:

```
with open("data1.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
   data_string = file.readline()
   data = eval(data_string)
   # (data["STRENGTH"])
   S1 = (float(data["STRENGTH"]))
file.close()
```

Now i can do something with the variable --> 'S1'

Here is the external text file 'data1.txt'

```
{'PLAYER': 'Oreo', 'STRENGTH': '11.75'}
```

... But i wanna change the strength value after a "battle" many thanks

Comment: You don't need `file.close()` if you are going to use `with` as a context manager. It does that for you. [Docs](http://docs.python.org/3.1/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're not understanding Python dict semantics?

Seems to me you're doing a lot of unnecessary things like `S1 = (float(data['STRENGTH']))` to try to manipulate and change values when you could be doing really simple stuff.

```
>>> data = {'PLAYER': 'Oreo', 'STRENGTH': '11.75'}
>>> data['STRENGTH'] = float(data['STRENGTH'])
>>> data
{'PLAYER': 'Oreo', 'STRENGTH': 11.75}
>>> data['STRENGTH'] += 1
>>> data
{'PLAYER': 'Oreo', 'STRENGTH': 12.75}
```

Maybe you should give [Native Data Types -- Dive Into Python 3](http://www.diveintopython3.net/native-datatypes.html) a read to see if it clears things up.

Comment: But the data from what you have type are not from a 'external' file source such as a .TXT file, I need the program to 'read' the .TXT file and change the STRENGTH value.

Comment: You can read and write the dict in and out of the text file all day long exactly the way you are doing, or better yet using `pickle` or similar as previously suggested. Generally, though, you want to be manipulating the values in memory (much faster) when the program is running, and only read to or write from files when you absolutely have to.

Comment: Can you please write me a example code? to change the value of 'strength'?

Comment: That's exactly what my answer does! The last 2 lines show you it changes from 11.75 to 12.75 (`data['STRENGTH'] += 1`).

Comment: I will need to use... With data1.txt open, readline()--> strength change to NEWER value. file.close() :)

Comment: Can you just show me a step by step guide? please :) just need 'with file open' --> and REPLACE STRENGTH with 0 or ADD 1 many thanks

Comment: TypeError: string indices must be integers <--im getting this when i use file.write()